# divs with spans inside not spacing correctly

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am using bootstrap's grid to mimic a table like structure. The spans take up two lines of space and look as expected but if I try to add a margin-bottom to the containing div it seems to add it to the top.

I want there to be space after each dive so they look a bit more grouped together. Is there a way to do that following this structure?

https://jsfiddle.net/daltonj1130/7Ltstbhp/

```js
var h = $('#x').height();
console.log(h);
$('.dclass').css('padding-bottom', 2 * h + 1).css('border', '1px solid grey')
```

```css
.dclass {
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div class="dclass">
  <span id="x" class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-3 col-lg-6" style="padding:0;">
    Action
    <select class="form-control" name="act1">
    </select>
  </span>
  <span class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-3 col-lg-6" style="padding:0;">
    Pay Type
    <select class="form-control" name="act2">
      <option value=""></option>
    </select>
  </span>
  <span class="col-xs-4 col-sm-4 col-md-2 col-lg-4" style="padding:0;">Date
    <input type="text" name="act3" class="form-control" value="date"></span>
  <span class="col-xs-4 col-sm-4 col-md-2 col-lg-4" style="padding:0;">Start Time
    <input type="time" name="act4" class="form-control" value="act4"></span>
  <span class="col-xs-4 col-sm-4 col-md-2 col-lg-4" style="padding:0;">End Time
    <input type="time" name="act5" class="form-control" value="act5"></span>
</div>

<div class="dclass">
  <span class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-3 col-lg-6" style="padding:0;">Action
    <input type="hidden" name="act" value="act"/>
    <select class="form-control" name="act1">
    </select>
  </span>
  <span class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-3 col-lg-6" style="padding:0;">Pay Type
    <select class="form-control" name="act2">
      <option value=""></option>
    </select>
  </span>
  <span class="col-xs-4 col-sm-4 col-md-2 col-lg-4" style="padding:0;">Date
    <input type="text" name="act3" class="form-control" value="date"></span>
  <span class="col-xs-4 col-sm-4 col-md-2 col-lg-4" style="padding:0;">Start Time
    <input type="time" name="act4" class="form-control" value="act4"></span>
  <span class="col-xs-4 col-sm-4 col-md-2 col-lg-4" style="padding:0;">End Time
    <input type="time" name="act5" class="form-control" value="act5"></span>
</div>

<div class="dclass">
  <span class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-3 col-lg-6" style="padding:0;">
    Action
    <select class="form-control" name="act1">
    </select>
  </span>
  <span class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-3 col-lg-6" style="padding:0;">Pay Type
    <select class="form-control" name="act2">
      <option value=""></option>
    </select>
  </span>
  <span class="col-xs-4 col-sm-4 col-md-2 col-lg-4" style="padding:0;">Date
    <input type="text" name="act3" class="form-control" value="date"></span>
  <span class="col-xs-4 col-sm-4 col-md-2 col-lg-4" style="padding:0;">Start Time
    <input type="time" name="act4" class="form-control" value="act4"></span>
  <span class="col-xs-4 col-sm-4 col-md-2 col-lg-4" style="padding:0;">End Time
    <input type="time" name="act5" class="form-control" value="act5"></span>
</div>
```

Comment: The jsfiddle attached to the question is the working version now. (initially it was what needed to be fixed)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up finding a fix that set the padding-bottom of the div to the height of the spans within it. I then added a margin-bottom to add space in between each div

Answer (score 0):

Your divs have no height. If you don't know the cause, just insert `height:auto !important` into their styles or class or whatever.

Comment: this did not seem to have any effect